# Remove space with mongoose

Tags: mongoose-schema

I am practising with the Mongoose schemes, the truth is that I do not know how to receive the data and from the scheme delete the spaces, I have the property trim: true but it only eliminates the spaces at the beginning and at the end.

```
contactPhone: { type: String, trim: true }
```

I have tried with default as follows:

```
contactPhone: { type: String, trim: true, default: function prueba() {
    let telefono = this.contactPhone.replace(/ /g, "");
    return telefono;
} },
```

but it gives me an error saying that it does not recognize the replace property. What I would like is that if someone writes 311 526 45 21 when saving it, it will be 3115264521.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the mongoose pre hook like this:

```
userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    let user = this;
    user.contactPhone = user.contactPhone.replace(/ /g, "");
    next();
})
```

now each time you create a new user using the create() function like this:

```
await UserModel.create({contactPhone:req.body.contactphone})
```

the create() function will fire the save() hook and it will remove all the whitespaces inside the contactPhone before saving the new user.
you can read more about the pre hook here [mongoose middlewares](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)